# How to set a list returned by AJAX to a list reference on the page using EL

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, el

I have a JSP page which is being called for the first time with a list of items.
On the selection of a dropdown (select) I am triggering the AJAX code to get products specific to the option selected and I want to overwrite the product list with more relevant products.

Is there a way I could set it to "${products}" or do I have to use another approach like hiding that div tag and displaying another.

My JSP page

```
<div>
  <c:forEach var="p" items="${products}">
    <table>
      <td>p.name</td>
      <td>p.description</td>
    </table>
  </c:forEach>
<div>
```

My script

```
// Ajax...
success: function(result) {
  if (result.length > 0) {
    // want to set the products list with the list returned
  }
}
```

My Controller

```
public List<Product> MyController() {
  // ...
  List<Product> products = prodcat.getList()
  return products
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply let me tell you my approach. I used AJAX Jackson and tried to pass the list of products to the view.I have a bidirectional mapping between My products(One)  and rating (Many) implicitly on object conversion it was going into an infinite loop because it was finding rating in product and product in rating.
I created another Model class and set only the attributes that I needed from the products class instead of sending the product list. **So in the end I just overwrote the div tag with the new elements I received.**

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to fix your problem, but first you should be aware that both `JSP` and `el` are server side technologies, which means that they execute on the server side to generate an `HTML` response that is sent to the client side to be rendered in the browser, so in your case once the products table is rendered in the client side on the first time, you will have to use some `JavaScript` code which is executed on the client side to remove/substitute that table content

**So the first way** is to put that table in a separate `JSP` file (e.g., `products_view.jsp` and
instead of returning `products` object, you return `ModelAndView` object from your controller method:

Controller

```
@RequestMapping( method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/products_view" )
public ModelAndView MyController() {
  // ...
  List<Product> products = prodcat.getList();
  model.addAttribute( "products", products );
  return new ModelAndView( "products_view" );
}
```

products_view.jsp

```
<div id="products_table">
  <table>
    <c:forEach var="p" items="${products}">
      <tr> 
        <td>p.name</td>
        <td>p.description</td>
      </tr>
    </c:forEach>
  </table>
<div>
```

AJAX

```
// Ajax...
success: function(result) {
  if (result.length > 0) {
    $("#products_table").html( response );
  }
}
```

**The other method** is you return a JSON or XML response of that product list from your controller, and then you populate that JSON response into your table in the client side, make sure that you have [`Jackson`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) jars in your dependencies list

Controller

```
@RequestMapping( method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/products_view", produces="application/json" )
public @ResponseBody List<Product> MyController()
  // ...
  List<Product> products = prodcat.getList();
  return products ;
}
```

AJAX

```
// Ajax...
dataType: "json",
success: function(result) {
  if (result.length > 0) {
    var productTableHTML = '<table>';
    $.each(response, function (key,value) {
      productTableHTML += 
        '<tr><td>' + key + '</td><td>' + value + '</td></tr>';     
    });
    productTableHTML += '</table>';
    $("#products_table").html( productTableHTML );
  }
}
```